# Wired Netoworking will not start

Tags: 12.04, networking, upgrade, network-manager, virtualhost

I have tried looking thorugh your forums as well as many others, and I cant seem to find a solution to my problem.

I currently have a Ubuntu 12.04 VM installed on a hyper-V. I upgraded this system from a 10.04 system using the do-release-upgrade option. I went through the process of configuring the network settings through Network Manager, but I still cannot connect to the network. I have started and stopped the network manager service a number of times. i have also restarted the machine too. I tried editing the /etc/network/interfaces file and that did not work. I even tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager to see if that would help, and it has not. Also for some reason when I set the gateway, I am not able to ping my gateway address.

Is there something that I am missing? Is there something I am doing wrong? I cant revert to the previous version of Ubuntu because I forgot to take a snapshot before upgrading. I ran the command killall -9 NetworkManager and that will allow the Wired network to connect, but i still cannot get to the internet for some reason. I tries using steps from this forum below and still no luck.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983054&page=4

Any help would be nice,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the IRC room to help fix this. The issue is that I am in a Hyper-V environment. This box was using a legacy network adapter when it was on 10.04. Now that it is on 12.04 I removed the legacy adapter and added a new adapter, and it works now. thanks to the user hydruid